# Source URL embedded in message for a contact form

Tags: php, contact-form

I've got a very simple PHP contact form, containing Email and Message.
I would like to add a functionality so that every time the contact form is sent I know the URL that it is being sent from, and I'd like to include it into the body of the message that gets sent to my email.

Here's the PHP code that runs the Contact form.

```
<?php 
$to = "email@email.com" ;

$from = "Something Broke!" ; 

$subject = "Something Broke!";


$fields = array(); 
$fields{"emailOptional"} = "Email:"; 
$fields{"message"} = "Message:";   
$body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){    $body .= sprintf("%s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 
if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
    echo 'sent';// we are sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..
}else{
    echo 'failed';// ... or to tell it that it wasn't sent    
    }
?>
```

And here's the markup:

```
<form method="post" action="widgetScript.php" id="contactForm">
<input type="text" name="emailOptional" placeholder="Your Email (optional)" />
<textarea rows="5" type="text" name="message" id="message"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="send" id="Submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I've found that you can use [_post_url] to get the current URL if I understand correctly - but I'm unsure what to do with it. Would appreciate all the help I could get

Answer (score 0):

In your php code,  use $ _SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the url the form was submitted from.

For more information on $_SERVER:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php